# I wanted to know why this animation doesn't fill the entire screen.

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make this animation expand the cell into a full screen. I don't exactly understand what I'm doing wrong. its expands the cell but not to a full screen

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let item = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomViewCell

    let screensize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0,delay: 0,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 6.0, animations: {() -> Void in
                    item.center.x = self.view.center.x
                    item.center.y = self.view.center.y
                    item.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: screensize.width/item.frame.size.width, y: screensize.height/item.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection view cell is in a different coordinate system from your `view`.

This means that when your item's location is at `view.center`, it might not appear at the centre of the view.

You need to convert `view.center` from the coordinate system of the view, to the coordinate system of the collection view, or whichever view is your cell's superview.

```
let point = view.convert(view.center, to: collectionView)
item.center.x = point.x
item.center.y = point.y
```